# Qt: Error while compiling Qt 5.0.1 on Windows, Visual Studio 2010 (VS2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, compiler-errors, qmake

I'm trying to compile Qt 5.0.1 for Windows under Visual Studio 2010 (VS2010), because of the famous problem with OpenGL, where the only the ES version of OpenGL is with the precompiled version of Qt.

I'm getting the error at qeglplatformcontext_p.h:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file 'EGL/egl.h': No such file or directory
```

However, the designated file and directory exist in the 3rdparty files of the Qt source in qtbase\src\3rdparty\angle\include.

The Qt I'm using is qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.1.zip

The steps I follow for compiling are

1- extract files in D:\Qt\Qt5.0.1

2- Open Visual Studio Command Prompt

3- Run the following commands in the directory mentioned in step 1:

```
set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2010
set QTDIR=D:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\qtbase
set PATH=%PATH%;D:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\qtbase\bin

configure -opensource -debug-and-release -developer-build -accessibility -opengl desktop -openvg -platform win32-msvc2010

..\jom\jom.exe -j 32
```

And then happens the error of EGL/egl.h after approx. 5 minutes.

What should I do to fix this compile error? Please advise.

Another question I have is about exceptions. How can I enable exceptions in this version of Qt? The command -exceptions or -no-exceptions is not valid anymore. Any ideas?

Thanks for any efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it. I downloaded the repository version using Git, and then used the following commands and it worked. Probably downloading it from the repository wasn't necessary, but this is what I got working so far (still compiling since half an hour with no errors).

```
set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2010
set QTDIR=D:\Qt\Qt5.0.1
set PATH=D:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\bin;%PATH%

configure -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2010 -exceptions

C:\Qt\jom\jom.exe -j 32
```

this will include OpenGL and the other libraries by default. It's not necessary to define them explicitly.

Good luck guys :)